# Are Django models tightly coupled with databases?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, graphene-django

Are Django Models tightly coupled with databases?

I want to create a web application using Django framework, but I don't want to use any database. By this, I mean that my data is stored in the network file system and I have already written python functions to read/write data from/to the file system.

i.e. I think I don't need anything like

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

How can I go about creating such an application using Django?

Comment: Can you clarify how you plan to use models, if at all?

Comment: Can I skip using Django models and still have a Django web app? If that is possible then it is awesome, my persistence APIs (python functions to read data from network file system) already return objects, I just want to serialize it and return

Comment: Yes you can use Django without models. You may want to take a look at DRF, their first example in serializers does not use Models https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers . But even that is optional, you can just return JSON if you want https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to create REST APIs, I want to create graphql APIs. In a nutshell, I want Django GraphQL APIs without using databases/ Django models